# How to use 1 id for everything instead of 3 (for the following code)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html (it's a card) where a class is added to change the look of it:

```
<div class="card-small-half" id="card-1">
    <a href="components/">
        <div class="action-bar">
            <p>Add Page</p>
            <i class="material-icons">add</i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and a switch made with a label that checks and unchecks an input type checkbox:

```
<div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-1"></label>
    <p id="switch-caption-1">Visible</p>
</div>
```

With the following Javascript I add a class called "card-disabled" to the card:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function check() {
        if (document.getElementById("input-1").checked) {
            document.getElementById("switch-caption-1").textContent = "Disabled";
            $('#card-1').addClass('card-disabled');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("switch-caption-1").textContent = "Visible";
            $('#card-1').removeClass('card-disabled');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('input-1').onchange = check;
    check();
}
```

I know in css you can call id's or classes like so:

`#switch-wrapper-1 input { /* styles */ }`
or
`#switch-wrapper-1 p { /* styles */ }`

How can I do this with javascript, so I don't have to use an id for every element and instead use a global id for every wrapper.

**EDIT:**
The wrapper and input id's *are* unique! I want to call the paragraph inside the unique wrapper element something like this:

`document.getElementById("switch-wrapper-1 p").textContent = "Disabled";`

The 'p' here means paragraph

Is this possible and if so: how?

Comment: Global id for every wrapper? Did you mean a css class? Id is unique.

Comment: the same id cannot be used for different elements. id is unique as @LeszekRepie said

Comment: @LeszekRepie I have a unique id for every wrapper and want call to an element inside that wrapper

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? I think you should re-phrase your question since using 1 id for different elements is not possible

Comment: @JoostdeLange attach event with jQuery (or just JS) like $(.switch-wrapper input).Checked() {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Query Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is your friend here. You can use CSS selectors to retrieve DOM elements. In your case this call would return the first paragraph child in the `#switch-wrapper-1` element.

```
var node = document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-1 p');
```

If you also use jQuery, then as suggested in comments, you can simply use the `$` function.

```
var $node = $('#switch-wrapper-1 p');
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for both javascript and jquery solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To select an individual element inside of an element with a specific ID using Javascript you can do:

`document.getElementById('hello').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];`

So in your example it would be:

`document.getElementById('switch-wrapper-1').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = check;`

The `[0]` is used because `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of all the child elements inside the parent element with the specified tag. Note that you will have to keep the unique ID on the input field if you want the `for` attribute on the label to function correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, did you see the answer that I currently marked as the right answer? I'm curious if that javascript solution is better or yours, can you tell me?

Comment: We submitted our answers at the same time, so I wasn't implying jorgonor was wrong. I do know that `querySelector` won't work in older browsers such as IE7, however in the vast majority of cases `querySelector` should be fine.